# Bullk insert only imports half of file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am executing a bulk insert that has worked fine up until today, nothing out of the ordinary, using the following code:

```
BULK
INSERT my_table
FROM 'e:\transfer\my_import.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
ERRORFILE = 'e:\transfer\my_errors.csv'
)
GO
```

The bulk insert is only importing half of the file each time however is not erroring.  It is importing exactly 50% of the rows in the CSV file.  So far I have tried:

1. Pasting the contents of the CSV file underneath itself to effectively double up the file.  This imports the first half as before, which in this case is the whole original file
2. Setting First and Last row to skip the first 3 and last 3 - no effect, still imports first half only
3. Deleting the middle few rows from the CSV file in case any rogue characters were indicating end of file - again, no errors, just imports half of a (slightly smaller) file.

I'm stumped as to why this could be happening!

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind so far is the disparity between ASCII and Unicode, where ASCII characters take up one byte and Unicode characters take up two bytes. Needless to say this is just a guess, and a wild one at that, but could anything have happened to your process where what used to be an ASCII file is now Unicode?

Comment: The file was downloaded from a website, and when downloaded is in UNIX format.  To fix the line endings, I open in TextPad and save as PC format.  This was working yesterday though, with the exact same approach

Comment: Tried saving as Unicode but Sql really didn't like that

Comment: I know it's old, but got same issue here. Did you manage to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

After "FROM 'e:\transfer\my_import.csv'", type a space and the word truncover.